# Why are my photographs (or videos?) counted against my storage limit?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I'm uploading photos to Google Storage using Picasa. I'm not using full resolution - I leave Google to resize them from full resolution.

Why is it using some of my storage limit? Might it be caused by uploaded videos?

Answer (score 1):

Yes if (i) your photos are over 2048 x 2048 pixels and (ii) your videos are longer than 15 minutes [ref](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/6558?hl=en-GB).